http only cookie not being passed during protected API call
During user registration and login, I created a jwt token and stored it using http only cookie.
The login controller is:
const loginUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { phone, password } = req.body;

  const user = await User.findOne({ phone });

  if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
    generateToken(res, user._id);

    res.status(200).json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      phone: user.phone,
      verified: user.verified,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      isVendor: user.isVendor,
      isDeliveryPartner: user.isDeliveryPartner,
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401); //unauthorized
    throw new Error("Invalid phone or password");
  }
});

and the generate_token code is:
const generateToken = (res, userId) => {
  const token = jwt.sign(
    {
      // 1st arg is object with payload
      userId,
    },
    process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    {
      expiresIn: "30d",
    }
  );
  // setting jwt as http Only cookie
  res.cookie("jwt", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development", // if in production then true, else false
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 30 days
  });
};

As a user I need to be a vendor or admin to create a product which is a protected route:
router.post("/create", protect, vendorOrAdmin, createProduct);
the middleware is as:
export const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;
  token = req.cookies.jwt; //jwt is name of the cookie
  if (token) {
    //if there is a token, we need to verify it
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.userId).select("-password");
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(401);
      throw new Error("Not authorized, token failed");
    }
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Not authorized, no token");
  }
});


export const vendorOrAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user && (req.user.isVendor || req.user.isAdmin)) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Not authorized as an vendor or an admin");
  }
};

in the frontend, I have used redux toolkit for API calls:
apiSlice:
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8001";

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: BASE_URL,
  }),
  tagTypes: ["Product"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({}),
});

usersApiSlice:
export const userApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    login: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: `${USERS_URL}/login`,
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      }),
    }),
    register: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: `${USERS_URL}/register`,
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      }),
    }),
})

productsApiSlice:
export const productsApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    createProduct: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: `${PRODUCTS_URL}/create`,
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Product"],
    }),
    uploadProductImage: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: `/api/upload`,
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

Now when I try to create product by signing in, then I get the error:

Not authorized, no token

This is the function that handles the creation of product :
const handleProductCreate = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await createProduct({
        name,
        brand,
        image1,
        primaryCategory,
        secondaryCategory,
        tertiaryCategory,
        description,
        sellingPrice,
        actualPrice,
        off,
        sizes,
        seller,
      }).unwrap();
      toast.success("Product Created");
      navigate("/vendor");
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error(error?.data?.message || error.error);
    }
  };

I don't understand why I am getting the no token error.
I have tried using prepareHeaders in the fetchBaseQuery. In postman while testing API, everything seems fine but in the actual localhost it doesn't seem to work
Also, these are the headers:

